# Setting up an indirect server for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

So, I have a bit of a dilemma. I've been attempting to run a Minecraft server from home that I can access from the college through a VPN (Hamachi) in order to avoid port forwarding problems which have all slapped me in the face for days.

At the college, I realized how I can't install any sort of program directly into the computers there. Moreover, even if I could access the C: drive, roaming profiles are active there and so it would need to be repeated each time I got onto a different computer (let alone any of my friends).

So far, I have no idea what to do. I have a VPN set up on Hamachi that I've tested on other computers with Hamachi already installed. That works fine, but I can't install the Hamachi client onto the college computers because it requires access to the system32 drivers folder, which I don't have.

I need a simple, relatively small program that is a self-contained .exe or something similar that can just be dropped onto a desktop and told a few things to do in order to connect to the server. No drivers or anything installed in program files. I can place things into the AppData folder, if that's of any help.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I'm open to anything that can work at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best bet would be to figure out your port forwarding issue by asking about it on Superuser.com. Then set up the server at your house and just run MineCraft from school.

Almost all VPN clients need to create a virtual adapter to create the tunnel. This will require you to have Admin rights on the machine that you want to install the client on. Based on what you have said that is not possible.

Do you have access to the router where you live to try and properly configure the port forwarding? Also are you setting up a standard MineCraft server or using something like Bukkit?

Comment: I have complete access to the router. The issues with that is there are technically two routers, one acting as a modem and the other acting as the actual wireless router (I think). Then there are the firewalls, either within the router/routers or within the software on that computer. Either way, I'm able to modify anything on there. I'm just going with a standard server, no modifications of any kind.

Comment: The modem should be configured in bridge mode allowing all connections to go to the router. If not port forwarding would be required on both but I strongly suggest you set the modem to bridge mode. What type of router and modem do you have? Also what operating system are you running. Also if your modem supports it I suggest you use DynDNS (dyndns.com) to get a domain name for your server. This will allow you to not remember the IP address or if the IP address changes it will update itself.

Comment: I have a Netgear Modem Router (DGN2000) and a Netgear N600 Wireless Dual Band Router. And the computer running the server is using Windows 7.

Comment: That should be extremely easy to configure. Do you understand how port forwarding works? Also have you confirmed that your port forwarding issues are not an issue with your Windows 7 Firewall?

Comment: Should be. The modem router itself is on its way out of usefulness. I understand bits of how it works. And I've added an exception to the windows firewall for this to work.

Comment: It's difficult to explain on here really with out being in closer contact. I will try to write you some instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the extremely late reply. But here is a tool which doesn't use Hamachi or port forwarding, and bypasses the router firewall. 
This doesn't need any administrator privileges.
The program is called [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

You need an account for it to work. The ip changes every time you close the ngrok prompt.

Comment: nrok doesn't seem to require an account if you read through the documentation, are you sure that is correct?

Comment: @Ferrybig You don't need an account if you are tunneling with http. To tunnel with tcp (which is required for minecraft I think) you need an account. The account is free (Unless you decide to upgrade to get their 'features').